# What's up with desktop.ini?

Tags: virus, desktop

I have been having lots and lots of `desktop.ini` files everywhere around my computer.

I have no idea what does that do to my computer. Is it a virus?

Comment: You enabled the option to view hidden files and folders. These (normally hidden) files hold the information on how to display the items in the folder they are contained in. Not a virus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desktop.ini files are files that determine the way a folder is displayed by Windows. These files can be found in any folder, anywhere on your computer, as long as that folder has a custom appearance set for it. I wouldn't worry too much about them.

Comment: oh, so what will happen if you delete it? @Nayncore

Comment: Is this normal to have two desktop.ini in the same folder?